# multiple output prediction from sklearn sgd classifer?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, gradient-descent

I did created a scikit model which is similar to this. But now I want to extract two outputs. I don't know how to pass this while training. I did tried similar to Keras. [y,z] as list. But its not working in scikit. Did anyone tried this before?

```python
import numpy as np
from sklearn import linear_model
X = np.array([[-1, -1], [-2, -1], [1, 1], [2, 1]])
Y = np.array([1, 1, 2, 2])
Z = np.array([1, 1, 2, 2])
clf = linear_model.SGDClassifier(max_iter=1000)
clf.fit(X, [Y, Z])
```

Output:

```python
ValueError: bad input shape (2, 4)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your target `[Y, Z]` is not what you think it is:

```python
[Y, Z]
# [array([1, 1, 2, 2]), array([1, 1, 2, 2])]
```

Arguably, what you want should have four rows like your `X`, i.e.

```python
W = np.array([[1, 1], [1, 1], [2, 2], [2, 2]])
W
# result:
array([[1, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [2, 2],
       [2, 2]])
```

But even with this change, you will again get a similar error:

```python
clf.fit(X, W)
[...]
ValueError: bad input shape (4, 2)
```

because, as clearly mentioned in the SGDClassifier [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier.html#sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier.fit), your dependent variable `y` should have a single column:

> `fit`*(X, y, coef_init=None, intercept_init=None, sample_weight=None)*
>
> ***y : numpy array, shape (n_samples,)***
>
> Target values

Arguably, what you are looking for, is scikit-learn's [`MultiOuputClassifier`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.multioutput.MultiOutputClassifier.html) for [multioutput classification](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/multiclass.html#multioutput-classification):

```python
from sklearn.multioutput import MultiOutputClassifier

sgd = linear_model.SGDClassifier(max_iter=1000)
multi_target_sgd = MultiOutputClassifier(sgd, n_jobs=-1)
multi_target_sgd.fit(X, W)
```

The `fit` now works OK, giving the following output:

```python
MultiOutputClassifier(estimator=SGDClassifier(alpha=0.0001, average=False, class_weight=None, epsilon=0.1,
       eta0=0.0, fit_intercept=True, l1_ratio=0.15,
       learning_rate='optimal', loss='hinge', max_iter=1000, n_iter=None,
       n_jobs=1, penalty='l2', power_t=0.5, random_state=None,
       shuffle=True, tol=None, verbose=0, warm_start=False),
           n_jobs=-1)
```

Just keep in mind that the subject classifier does not do anything more sophisticated than fitting one classifier per single target output; from the [docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.multioutput.MultiOutputClassifier.html) again:

> Multi target classification
>
> This strategy consists of fitting one classifier per target. This is a
>   simple strategy for extending classifiers that do not natively support
>   multi-target classification

Comment: I just converted the custom keras model into scikit. Thanks for the detailed information. I understood!

Answer (score 0):

*(Disclaimer: My ML is a bit rusty, but I have a feeling I know what you're looking for, and this was too long to be a comment)*

The shape that you're passing to `clf.fit` is incorrect.

First you're passing X, which is fine, it's an array with arrays inside it and each of those inner arrays contains the values for the features (right?).

Now, the second argument that you're passing is an array formed out of Y and Z.

If we look at the [**documentation for fit**](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier.html#sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier.fit), we can see that the fit function expects a Y which is of the following format:

```
y : numpy array, shape (n_samples,)
Target values
```

That means that it has to be a single array with those n samples.

I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to match to with `[Y, Z]` as in what result you're expecting when you'll call `clf.predict`, but I think you're not forming the target array correctly.

Maybe you should be forming your arrays as Y = Y + Z:

```
YZ = [ [1,1], [1,1], [2,2], [2,2] ]
```

By using this YZ array, when running for example `clf.predict([-1, -1])` the following output:

```
clf.predict([-1, -1])
output: [1,1]
```